# Area under the peak of a FFT in Python

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to do some tests before I proceed analyzing some real dataset via FFT, and I've found the following problem.

First, I create a signal as the sum of two cosines and then use `rfft` to to the transformation (since it has only real values):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq

# Number of sample points
N = 800
# Sample spacing
T = 1.0 / 800.0

x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
y = 0.5*np.cos(10*2*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.cos(200*2*np.pi*x)

# FFT
yf = rfft(y)
xf = rfftfreq(N, T)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,5))
ax[0].plot(x,y)
ax[1].plot(xf, 2.0/N*np.abs(yf))
```

As it can be seen from the definition of the signal, I have two oscillations with amplitude 0.5 and frequency 10 and 200. Now, I would expect the FFT spectrum to be something like two deltas at those points, but apparently increasing the frequency broadens the peaks:

[image: FFT]

From the first peak it can be infered that the amplitude is 0.5, but not for the second. I've tryied to obtain the area under the peak using `np.trapz` and use that as an estimate for the amplitude, but as it is close to a dirac delta it's very sensitive to the interval I choose. My problem is that I need to get the amplitude as exact as possible for my data analysis.

EDIT: As it seems to be something related with the number of points, I decided to increment (now that I can) the sample frequency. This seems to solve the problem, as it can be seen in the figure:

[image: FFT with more points]

However, it still seems strange that for a certain number of points and sample frequency, the high frequency peaks broaden...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect peaks in list of numbers and record their positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53914486/detect-peaks-in-list-of-numbers-and-record-their-positions)

Comment: If you can (somehow) derive an analytical expression for the peak then you can infer its height by fitting, which might be more accurate than numerical integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not strange , you have leakage of the frequency bins. When you discretize the signal (sampling) needed for the Fourier transfrom , frequency bins are created which are frequency intervals where the the amplitude is calculated. And each bin has wide which is given by the sample_rate / num_points . So , the less the number of bins the more difficult is to assign precise amplitudes to every frequency. Other problems in choosing the best sampling rate exist such as the shannon-nyquist theorem to prevent aliasing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem . But depending on the problem sometimes there some custom rates used for sampling. E.g. when dealing with audio a sampling rate of 44,100 Hz is widely used , cause is based on the limits of the human hearing. So it depends also on nature of the data you want to perform analysis as you wrote. Anyway , since this question has also theoretical value , you can also check  https://dsp.stackexchange.com for some useful info.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment to George's answer, but yet I cannot.

Maybe a starting point for your research are the properties of the Discrete Fourier Transform.
The signal in the time domain is actual the cosines multiplied by a box window which transforms into the frequency domain as the convolution of the deltas with the sinc function. The sinc functions will smear the spectrum.

However, I am not sure we are observing spectral leakage here, since the window fits exactly to the full period of cosines. The discretization of the bins might still play a role here.

Comment: You are right , but I wasn't referring to this spectral leakage . I referred to the leakage of the frequency bins to others that are not supposed to . I called it spectral leakage since stack overflow it's not about the theoretical topics and I just name it like that while trying to give a small compact answer that is directly correlated with the problem he is facing , which is definitely the discretization of the bins. But sure the formal definition is the one you stated. That's the reason I suggested dsp.stackexhange.com for further analyzing this topic.